# How to remove product from collection using shopify api

Tags: collections, e-commerce, shopify, product

https://wetion.myshopify.com/admin/collects/.jsonproduct_id=9706757444&collection_id=380751892';
I need to remove a product from the collection.is it possible?

```
$delete_exist_collect =  array();
for($i=0 ; $i < $custom_collectionss ; $i++)
{
    $delete_exist_collect = $product_data_collection['custom_collections'][$i]['id'];
    $urli = $to_storeurl_shopify.'/admin/collects/.json?product_id='.$response->product->id.'&collection_id='.$delete_exist_collect;    
    echo $urli;
    $newurl = str_replace(" ","",$urli);
    $shopcurl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
    curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$to_shopify_u_p);
    curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $responsee = curl_exec ($shopcurl);
    curl_close ($shopcurl);         
    $product_data_collection = json_decode($responsee,TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work, but have you looked at shopify's documentation for manipulating collections? https://help.shopify.com/manual/products/collections/manual-shopify-collection

Comment: when I update the one product that time removes that product to all collection(category). can you help me for that using Shopify API

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about shopfiy. If you post your attempts at solving the problem in your question you have a better chance at getting an answer though. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance.

Comment: I was added my code and  thank you for response